# disable copy paste in kendoeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Disable the copy paste in kendo editor when we switch to different tabs.

This is my below code which I have tried but not working

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').on("cut copy paste", function(e) {
            e. prevent Default();
        });
    });
</script>​
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txArNcrLineDescription').bind('copy paste cut', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); //disable cut,copy,paste

        });
    });
```

Comment: You posted a question about Kendo UI, a JavaScript framework. The `.NET` tag isn't relevant. This question won't even be shown to people interested in jQuery and Kendo UI

Answer (score 2):

```
$($("#txArNcrLineDescriptionValue").data().kendoEditor.body).bind("cut copy paste", 
    function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Please provide description to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: A good answer should explain what it does. Why does *this* fix the problem? How is it different from the original code?